# How do I implement the overflow code? I do not know what's wrong

Tags: verilog, fibonacci

How do I implement the overflow code?

I do not know what's wrong. A result is a negative number in the middle.Below is the code snippet

```
module fibonacci(input clk, input rst, output [7:0]out, output reg overflow);

reg [7:0]a,b;

always@(posedge rst)
begin
    a =8'b0;
    b =8'b1;
end
always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if ( a < 8'b11111111 ) begin
        b = a + b ;
        a = b - a ;

    end

    else begin

    overflow = 1'b1;   //is that wrong??

    end
end

assign out = a ;

endmodule
```

and testbench code here

```
initial begin

rst = 1;
clk =0;

#0.5
rst = 0;
end

always begin
#1 
clk = !clk;
end

fibonacci fib(clk,rst,out,overflow);
endmodule
```

[image]

Let me know what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this negative number is that the number is interpreted in the [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). The actual number you expect after `89` is `144`, which is `10010000`in binary. In the two's complement representation, however, the most-significant bit is the sign of the number. A '1' indicates that this should be a negative number, which can be calculated as follows:

```
~10010000 + 1 = 01101111 + 1 = 01110000 = (-)112
```

There are by the way several other catches to the code you posted. Let me first answer this question:

> overflow = 1'b1;   //is that wrong??

Not this particular line, but the way `overflow` is handled is not completely correct. In your code, `overflow` can only become `x`or `1`. It will never be `0`. You should assign `overflow` to `0` in the first part of you conditional block and in the reset part.

The second thing is that you should use [non-blocking assignments](https://www.nandland.com/articles/blocking-nonblocking-verilog.html) in Verilog to create sequential logic. In your code, you are using blocking assigments, which means that you first update `b`, and then update `a` with the already updated value `b`. If you need to use blocking assignments, you should create a [combinational block](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-process-part1.html).

Furthermore, you should combine the clock sensitive part and the reset sensitive part, so that `a`, `b`, and `overflow` are all modified by the same `always` block.

All these suggestions would roughly translate to:

```
always @(*)
begin
    b_next = a + b;
    a_next = b_next - a;
end 

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
    if (~rst) begin
        a <= 8'b0;
        b <= 8'b1;
        overflow <= 1'b0;
    end
    else if (a < 8'b11111111) begin
        b <= b_next;
        a <= a_next;
        overflow <= 1'b0    
    end
    else begin
        overflow <= 1'b1;
    end
end
```

As you can see, I also transformed the reset to an asynchronous, active-low reset. Although this is not mandatory, it is pretty common. The reset-signal is meant to keep all flops in reset-state, even when the power of a device comes up slowly. If the reset-signal is active-high, the signal itself may come up slowly.

Comment: note that `b <= b+a; a <= b-a;` logically behaves differently than the OP's example with blocking assignments. What was the intention of this code? This fix might not be correct.

Comment: @Serge you are right. My original intend was to show how sequential logic would look like in Verilog. However, it was indeed confusing because the behaviour of my suggested code would be different than the behaviour of the original code. Therefore, I editted the code, so that it will show similar behaviour to the code in the original post.